# Selecting class that was added dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, toggle

i'm trying to make changes to a div with a class name added with addClass(). 
but i can't get it work.

the div. clicking this div would remove "one" from the class, and replace it with "two", which i've managed to do.

```
<div class="product one">
    Click
</div>
```

and the jquery. unfortunately, i cant seem to remove "two" and add "three" or apply any changes on jquery to "two".

```
$('.product').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('one').addClass('two');
    TweenLite.to(".home_loop", 0.3, {height:110});
});

$('.two').on('click', function() {
    $('this').removeClass('two').addClass('three');
    TweenLite.to(".home_loop", 0.3, {height:0}); 
});
```

here's a simplified example (with the tweenlite stripped out)
used an inspector to see the class changes when i click on the words "Click".

http://jsfiddle.net/do6t4pa5/3/show/

also i tried using .toggle but it will make the link in the div not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/do6t4pa5/4/)

Code for reference

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.product').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('one').addClass('two');
    $('.two').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('two').addClass('three');
});
});
});
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

}).on('click','.product',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('one').addClass('two');
}).on('click','.two',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('two').addClass('three');
});
```